# PHP - Zend Amazon AWS S3 - Loading image from bucket

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have this:

```
<img src="loadImage.php?p=sdfdf7s8sf9sf">
```

Which calls this, a Zend Framework S3 thingy, which should create a signed URL to show my image in the browser.

```
<?php
    require_once 'Zend/Service/Amazon/S3.php';

    function get_s3_signed_url($bucket, $resource, $AWS_S3_KEY, $AWS_s3_secret_key, $expire_seconds) {
        $expires = time()+$expire_seconds;

        $string_to_sign = "GET\n\n\n{$expires}\n/".str_replace(".s3-eu-west-1.amazonAWS.com","", $bucket)."/$resource";
        $signature = urlencode(base64_encode((hash_hmac("sha1", utf8_encode($string_to_sign), $AWS_s3_secret_key, TRUE))));

        $authentication_params = "AWSAccessKeyId=".$AWS_S3_KEY;
        $authentication_params.= "&Expires={$expires}";
        $authentication_params.= "&Signature={$signature}";

        return $link = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonAWS.com/{$bucket}/{$resource}?{$authentication_params}";
    }

    $aws_access_key_id = "xxx";
    $aws_s3_secret = "xxx";

    $myBucket = "myBucketName.s3-eu-west-1.amazonAWS.com";
    $myObject = "website-normal-thumbs/100001.JPG";
    $url = get_s3_signed_url( $myBucket, $myObject, $aws_access_key_id, $aws_s3_secret, 3800);

    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); 
    readfile($url);
?>
```

I literally started programming in PHP yesterday. This code does not throw any errors, although it must do cos it's not working. My S3 object is in my bucket, I have tested that and my access and secret key is correct. If I misspell `require_once 'Zend/Service/Amazon/S3.php'` as `require_once 'Zendddd/Serviceeee/Amazonnnn/S3.php'` I get an error, so Zend is there and working. I just get a little image icon, with no image!

Maybe I could work it out if it showed me an error message!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple. All you need to do is to change

```
$myBucket = "myBucketName.s3-eu-west-1.amazonAWS.com";
```

to

```
$myBucket = "myBucketName";
```

because otherwise the link assembled in `get_s3_signed_url` will be faulty (`https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonAWS.com/myBucketName.s3-eu-west-1.amazonAWS.com/website-normal-thumbs/100001.JPG?...` instead of `https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonAWS.com/myBucketName/website-normal-thumbs/100001.JPG?...`)

And the reason why you don't see an error message most probably is the `header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");` command. This will lead the browser to interpret the result as an image instead of printing error messages.